# How to quote all fields in CSV in regex

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I have a string in CSV format as follows:

```
chocolate,2,sugar,,flour,5,water,,,vanila,1
```

I want to quote all fields with single quotes including empty fields as

```
'chocolate','2','sugar','','flour','5','water','','','vanila','1'
```

I want to do that in Perl. I had tried to replace comma (,) with ',' then adding single quotes at the beginning and the end. Is there any other easy and efficient and direct method to do that in Perl?

Edit: added the code that I have already tried.

```
my $str = "chocolate,2,sugar,,flour,5,water,,,vanila,1";
my $find = ",";
my $replace = "','";
$find = quotemeta $find;

$str =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
$str = "'".$str."'";
```

Comment: What do you mean, "other"? What have you tried?

Comment: With your experience I am sure you know that Stack Overflow is about helping with *specific* programming problems. Unless you show us a program and explain your problem we can't be expected to help you. Please show show your code, and describe the problem with it that you cannot solve

Comment: Please also note that it is non-standard to use single-quotes to enclose a CSV field, and you need to know with *absolute assurance* how the data source uses commas, double-quotes, and single-quotes before you can solve this question yourself or ask for help with it. None of this information is in the question.

Comment: Is this homework? The data seem to indicate that it probably is.

Comment: Please define *CSV format*! Is your file format yours to design, or does it need to be compatible with some CSV-generating or -consuming tool you don't control?  How do you represent values in fields that contain single quotes, or commas, or doesn't that ever happen?

Comment: I had tried this solution and the code is added to the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

With `Perl`, you can do it in command line with the following command. It basically splits the text with commas `,` then encloses each value with quotes then it join values again with comma in a single string.

```
perl -nle 'print join ",", map{"'\''$_'\''"} split /,/, $_, -1' infile
'chocolate','2','sugar','','flour','5','water','','','vanila','1'
```

Comment: This is a copy of my answer...?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to an **awk** solution, this would work:

```
$ awk -F "," -v OFS="," -v sq="'" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i = sq $i sq; print}' infile
'chocolate','2','sugar','','flour','5','water','','','vanila','1
```

This just sets input and output field separators to `,`, then loops over all fields and puts quotes around them.

The `sq` bit is a way to get single quotes into the command.

Or with **sed**:

```
$ sed 's/\([^,]*\)/'"'"'\1'"'"'/g' infile
'chocolate','2','sugar','','flour','5','water','','','vanila','1'
```

This look for groups of characters other than `,` of length zero or more, then surrounds them with quotes. It's a bit of a quote battlefield because the single quoted string ends, then we add a single quote between double quotes, then we continue the single quoted string, resulting in `'"'"'` just to get a single quote.

And finally, using **Perl**:

```
$ perl -nle 'print join ",", map{"'\''$_'\''"} split /,/, $_, -1' infile
'chocolate','2','sugar','','flour','5','water','','','vanila','1'
```

This splits the input string by `,`, maps the resulting list elements to their quoted version, then joins again using `,`.